# How to find dividers using multiple group in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a script that will evaluate all the radio buttons/checkbox on change event. If at least one selected item with a custom attribute "terminator", it will hide all the of the next dividers that have a class "questionPanel".

Following is the the code that does the search for the next divider

```
control.closest(".questionPanel").nextAll(".questionPanel").addClass(className).hide();
```

Now, I need to add one more thing to search for and hide if available.

I need to search for any `fieldset` that is located in the current div with the class "questionPanel") then I want to hide all the next "fieldset".

I tried to add a line like so but that did not do anything

```
control.closest(".questionPanel").nextAll("fieldset").addClass(className).hide();
```

How can I find all the next fieldsets and hide them?

I created a fiddle to show you the script in action and it is located on this link
https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nextAll()` method will select following sibling elements. Since the `fieldset` elements aren't siblings with the `.questionPanel` element, nothing is selected.

> How can I find all the next fieldsets and hide them?

If you want to select the following `fieldset` elements, you need to select the closest `.survey-control-fieldset` element, and then select the following `fieldset` siblings:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4pLghLn/)

```
control.closest('.survey-control-fieldset').nextAll('fieldset').addClass(className).hide();
```

Comment: I am not sure I explained what I need correctly. but I need to hide all the fieldset following the existing fieldset inside the current div with the class questionPanel but not all the fieldsets. the code seems to be hiding the wrong thing

Comment: @MikeA .. I think I understand now.. see the update.

Comment: Thank you that did it :)